# Evaluate a readonly field upon creating a new object in Django 1.11 admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-modeladmin

Assuming a the following model

```
# models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    age = models.CharField(max_length=3) # dont mind the type, this is just an example :)
```

The desired behavior would be to have the `age` field hidden while the user creates a new `Person` object, and evaluate its value when the user submits the form. Also, the `age` field should be visible when views the object instance in admin.

To achieve this, I created a `ModelAdmin` with a custom `ModelForm` as follows

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import Person
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PersonForm, self).clean()
        birthdate = cleaned_data.get('birthdate')
        cleaned_data['age'] = relativedelta(datetime.date.today(), birthdate).years
        return cleaned_data

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PersonForm
    exclude = ('age',)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

However, after submitting the form, the `age` field does not get populated, possibly because it is excluded. If I remove the `exclude` then it works, but the form displays the `age` field which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: You should consider whether you really need an age field at all. It would need to somehow change on every birthday. This would be better provided via a method or property that calculates the current age from the birthdate when required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of custom form you can use `ModelAdmin`'s [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method:

```
 class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        birthdate = form.cleaned_data.get('birthdate')
        age = relativedelta(datetime.date.today(), birthdate).years 
        obj.age = age
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return ('age',)
        return self.exclude
```

Also you probably can use [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```
 class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('age',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        birthdate = form.cleaned_data.get('birthdate')
        age = relativedelta(datetime.date.today(), birthdate).years 
        obj.age = age
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Thank you. The `age` field is not visible when viewing the object instance. I will edit my question to include this.

Comment: @Demetris correct, form validations will not affect `age` field.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can hide the input from form.

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import Person
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    age = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PersonForm, self).clean()
        birthdate = cleaned_data.get('birthdate')
        cleaned_data['age'] = relativedelta(datetime.date.today(), birthdate).years
        return cleaned_data
```

You can use that form only when object is none (create case).

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if not obj:
            kwargs['form'] = PersonForm
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also hide it when viewing/editing the object instance in admin?